# GCE ssh internal ip Connection closed by foreign host

Tags: php, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have 2 instances in the same project, and inside one instance(a) 
i want to connect to another instance(b) via ssh using the internal ip 
but the telnet  22 give me "Connection closed by foreign host".

I want to connect via ssh because in a php project, i want to execute ssh2_exec to remote launch a php file.

The firewall configuration is:
[image]
There is a way to solve this, thnks.

Comment: Check the listen address of the SSH server. Also, check the firewall

Comment: The project use the default-allow-ssh

Answer (score 6):

Not firewall: you are able to "connect" to the other server, but it doesn't like you. If you were firewalled out, you wouldn't connect at all.

Options could be (among many others)

- you are trying to SSH as "root" but root is not permitted to SSH in.
- you are trying to connect as another user that does not have permission.
- the user you are trying to connect at has no shell (or is set to '/bin/nologin')
- the password you are providing is incorrect
- the certificate(s) you are providing are not correct
- the server is set to only allow certain IPs (check /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny)
- the server does not allow connection through telnet (telnet passes username password unsecured so may be blocked, use SSH instead. Is telnet.d running/configured?)

Check logs on destination server for more clues.

---

Suggested solution:

- connect to the first server using SSH, then run "ssh user:pass@server" to test the connection from one server to the next. If that fails, get that working first.
- to do it programatically in php, try with phpseclib (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) - it's a very old library but easy to debug.

Comment: telnet'ing on port 22 should have given him the SSH broadcast message. eg. `SSH-2.0-whatever`. At that point he should have been able to type `SSH-2.0-whatever` in, hit enter and then start getting SSH packets (the first of which would be to negotiate the various algorithms). The fact that he got "Connection closed by foreign host". instead of `SSH-2.0-whatever` makes me think it actually could be a firewall issue.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you - it MIGHT be firewall, but a firewall block (or incorrect IP address/port) should give a "could not connect"/"connect failed" message. For you to get the SSH broadcast message you need firewall open, remote connections permitted for the user, shell available for the user and the telnet service running on the server, otherwise the connection is opened and then dumped without ceremony - which is what the OP described. So that's why I say not firewall and check the list I described - but there are different configs and telnets out there so it could be.

Comment: i think this is more elavorate because i can connect via gcloud to the instances via public ip, but inside one instances in the same project i can't connect via ssh to another instances in the same project.

Comment: As in can't even connect through "manual" ssh from one instance to the other? If that's the case, you should try to get that working first. Is there any way you can connect to the second host to check logs?

Answer (score 0):

In the default network created for you with the project, SSH is enabled in the firewall.

But if you created your own network, you need to add manually your firewall rules, including SSH, and tag your instances with those rules.

Comment: I use the default-allow-ssh and i want to communicate in the same project vm1  us-east1-c  f1-micro 10.142.0.2 RUNNING, vm2 us-east1-c  g1-small 10.142.0.7  RUNNING